# Parsing XML in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle

I have an interesting situaiton in oracle. We store an xml string in a field and part of as follows:

```
<dc:subject>info1</dc:subject>  <dc:subject>info2</dc:subject><dc:subject>info3</dc:subject>
```

And when i am querying this field, I use the following:

```
m.M_DC.extract('/qualifieddc/dc:subject/text()', 'xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"').getStringVal() "INFO",
```

And the resultant INFO area becomes "info1info2info3".

Is there any oracle function or a way to make this info area as "info1, info2, info3" ?

Any help would be appreciated...

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

XML in Oracle is a nightmare. You can try something like this (XMLTABLE to the rescue):

```
 > select wmsys.wm_concat(''||column_value) text
  2  from
  3  xmltable(
  4     XMLNAMESPACES('http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/' as "dc"),
  5     '$xml/qualifieddc/dc:subject/text()'
  6     passing xmltype('<qualifieddc xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/
">' ||
  7             '<dc:subject>info1</dc:subject>  <dc:subject>info2</dc:subject><
dc:subject>info3</dc:subject>' ||
  8         '</qualifieddc>') as "xml");

TEXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

info1,info2,info3
```

Note that I'm using wmsys.wm_concat for concatenation, which is not recommended. Use any other stragg implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think that would be a transform rather than a query.  Are you familiar with XSL?  If so, the look at the XMLTransform() examples, and it should be pretty easy from there:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions254.htm#SQLRF06171

Answer (score -1):

**This code will  help  you.**

> DECLARE
>    x XMLType := XMLType(
>      ' 
>       info1
>     info2
>     info3');
>     BEGIN
>    FOR r IN (
>      SELECT ExtractValue(Value(p),'/dc/text()') as name
>          FROM   TABLE(XMLSequence(Extract(x,'/dc'))) p
>      ) LOOP
>
> END LOOP;
>   END;

code tested by me in plsql developer.